# Shared pointer with predefined maximum use count

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

**Context**: I have a queue that supports single-read/single-write from two different(/or not) threads, to enforce this behaviour i.e. single-reader/single-writer at a time I need to limit the number of the threads owning the queue at a time to 2 (the writer already owns the queue), I was thinking then of creating a shared_ptr to the queue with a max ref count known at compile time set to 2. Hence my question is the below.

**Question**: Is there a way to implement a shared pointer (maybe using `unique_pointer`'s) with a maximum ref count that is known at compile time? My case is `max_ref_count = 2` i.e. exceeding ref count limit = 2 should be a compile-time error.

```
const auto p    = std::make_shared<2, double>(2159); //works fine
const auto q    = p; // works fine
const auto err1 = p; // does not compile
const auto err2 = q; // does not compile
```

Comment: And what should a compiler do for something like `const auto e = get_user_input() ? p1 : p2;`?

Comment: With compile time errors? I'd really doubt there's a good way to do that. Runtime errors, possible using a custom type.

Comment: @Eva aaah, not sure, this looks like a proof it's not possible?

Comment: I will say this is not possible at compile time but possible at runtime.

Comment: For the compiler to be able to catch this at compile time, it must know all the instances and how many times you plan on sharing them at compile time - and it should be impossible to create more of these at runtime, because if you can, you need the runtime check anyway. Is this something you'd really want?

Comment: Thank you! I can do the run-time version :) I think I will just go with "impossible" as an answer

Comment: Correct, it will be necessary to figure out how to violate several fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe in order to calculate something at compile time that will only be known at runtime.

Comment: What lies behind this question?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a shared pointer queue that only supports one writer (to which is owned ref_count = 1) and one reader is allowed and want to ensure that behaviour

Comment: What is a 'shared pointer queue'?  Please make your question more closely reflect what you are actually trying to do.  This is now looking like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20a,(Y%20or%20Why%3F)

Comment: Added a context, let me know if anything unclear

Comment: I don't get why reader write lock isn't sufficent in this case. A `std::shared_mutex`, writer `std::unique_lock` and reader `std::shared_lock`. Do you want every element to have its own two users? Also shared ptr doesn't prevent multiple writers.

Comment: single writer/single reader can be optimized! hence don't want to use mutex nor give access to multiple readers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Impossible at compile-time

What you're doing isn't possible at compile-time, only at runtime.
Note that `std::shared_ptr` is copyable, so it's possible that "copy paths diverge":

```cpp
std::shared_ptr A = /* ... */;
auto B = A;
auto C = A;
```

At this point, `B` and `C` don't know anything about each other, and there is no way to ensure that they do through the type system.
You can at best count the length of the copy path from `A` to `B` and subsequent copies, but not the global amount of copies.

This would require some form of stateful metaprogramming and C++ does not support that.

### Difficult at run-time

Note two problems:

1. `std::shared_ptr` is also expected to have thread-safe counting. This also means that `std::shared_ptr::use_count()` may not yield the most recent result and cannot be considered a reliable metric.
2. If you kept track of the use count yourself, you would need to allocate a new `int` in addition to the atomic counter that shared pointers already have.
   This is somewhat annoying, but doable.

### Single-threaded solution

If you don't consider the problems of multi-threading, you can just use [`std::shared_ptr::use_count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count) to keep track of uses.
This is a reliable metric in a single-threaded program.
You just need to make a wrapper for `std::shared_ptr` which throws whenever the limited is exceeded, which could happen in the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator.

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
  requires (N != 0)
struct limited_shared_ptr {
    using base_type = std::shared_ptr<T, N>;
    
  private:
    base_type base;

  public:
    // OK
    limited_shared_ptr(T* ptr) : base{ptr} {}

    // The following contains an immediately invoked lambda expression in the copy
    // constructor.
    // This is clunky, but necessary so that we throw *before* we copy-construct
    limited_shared_ptr(const limited_shared_ptr& other)
      : base{[this] -> base_type& {
        if (other.use_count() >= N) {
            throw /* ... */;
        }
        return other;
    }()} {}

    limited_shared_ptr& operator=(const limited_shared_ptr& other) {
        if (this != &other &&
            base.get() != other.get() &&
            other.get() != nullptr &&
            other.use_count() >= N) {
            throw /* ... */;
        }
        base = other.base;
        return *this;
    }

    // Move assignment or destruction cannot increase the use_count(), only
    // keep it constant or decrease it, so we can keep these operations defaulted.
    limited_shared_ptr(limited_shared_ptr&& other) = default;
    limited_shared_ptr& operator=(limited_shared_ptr&&) = default;
    ~limited_shared_ptr() = default;

    // TODO: expose more of the std::shared_ptr interface
};
```

### Multi-threaded solution

This is a little bit more complicating, and I will only provide the general outline.

You can create a `std::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter.
This custom deleter can contain a `std::atomic<std::size_t>` to keep *reliable* track of the use count.

```cpp
struct counting_deleter {
    std::atomic<std::size_t> use_count;
    void operator()(auto* ptr) const {
        delete ptr;
    }
};
```

With this, you don't need to manage resources yourself, but can let `std::shared_ptr` do it and access the deleter with `base.get_deleter<counting_deleter>()` any time.

In the copy constructor, similar to the single-threaded solution, you would check:

```cpp
counting_deleter* deleter = other.get_deleter<counting_deleter>();
std::size_t expected = deleter->use_count.load(std::memory_order::relaxed);
do {
    if (expected >= N) {
        // increasing the use_count would exceed the limit
        throw /* ... */;
    }
    // otherwise, attempt to increment atomically using a weak CAS
} while (!deleter->use_count.compare_exchange_weak(expected, expected + 1));
// note: the CAS can probably use std::memory_order::relaxed too
```

Basically, we check if increasing the use count is possible.
If not, we throw, otherwise we attempt to increment the `use_count` with `compare_exchange_weak`.

The copy assignment operator is analogous.
The other special member functions can be defaulted, since moving or destroying cannot blow the limit.

Answer (score -3):

The standard std::shared_ptr in C++ doesn't directly provide a mechanism to set a maximum reference count at compile time. However, you can achieve similar behavior by creating a custom smart pointer with a limited reference count. Here's a basic example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T, int MaxRefCount = 2>
class LimitedSharedPtr {
public:
    LimitedSharedPtr(T* ptr) : ptr_(ptr), refCount_(1) {
        if (refCount_ > MaxRefCount) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Exceeded maximum reference count");
        }
    }

    LimitedSharedPtr(const LimitedSharedPtr& other) : ptr_(other.ptr_), refCount_(other.refCount_) {
        if (refCount_ > MaxRefCount) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Exceeded maximum reference count");
        }
        refCount_++;
    }

    LimitedSharedPtr& operator=(const LimitedSharedPtr& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            release();
            ptr_ = other.ptr_;
            refCount_ = other.refCount_;
            if (refCount_ > MaxRefCount) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Exceeded maximum reference count");
            }
            refCount_++;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~LimitedSharedPtr() {
        release();
    }

    T* get() const {
        return ptr_;
    }

private:
    void release() {
        refCount_--;
        if (refCount_ == 0) {
            delete ptr_;
        }
    }

    T* ptr_;
    int refCount_;
};

int main() {
    LimitedSharedPtr<double, 2> p(new double(2159));
    LimitedSharedPtr<double, 2> q = p; // works fine
    LimitedSharedPtr<double, 2> err1 = p; // throws runtime_error
    LimitedSharedPtr<double, 2> err2 = q; // throws runtime_error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you should implement move-constructor and move-assignment to make behave in an acceptable way.

Comment: Won't `refCount_` be incorrect with the copies? And `refCount > MaxRefCount` is also incorrect.

Comment: Also, OP wanted compile time errors, not run time...

Comment: sorry not mentioned in my question, but the ref_count shoulf be thread safe